# Selenium Webdriver with Certificate Authentication in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, certificate

I am trying to automate the connection to a secure site that requires certificate authentication, in Python. This is from **Windows**, and does not have to be headless. My organisation does not play well with Firefox, so I have chosen to do this in **Chrome**. The certificate is a **.pfx**

I have come across older posts saying it cant be done at all with **Chromedriver** but a potential workaround would be to create a profile and import the certificate to that profile. When running the code, I reference the profile.

My code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('user-data-
dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\User\\WinPython-
64bit-3.5.4.0Qt5\\python-
3.5.4.amd64\\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get('https://www.securesite.com')
```

This code results in a **"This site can’t be reached"** response. When trying it manually, a prompt will popup to choose confirm the certificate to use and I am able to proceed to the site successfully.

When viewing **certmgr.mmc** I can see the certificate is imported under **Personal** as well as I have imported it to **Trusted Root CA**. From **Chrome** though when I view certificates, I find it **only under Personal**.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, and I am hoping that during recent times - a solution has been found so someone would be able to advise me.

Thank you

Comment: Just open the application link using selenium without coding for handling certificate, then accept it. Then again start the application using selenium and check whether it is asking for certificate again or not. I guess in chrome it won't ask. In Firefox and IE it used to ask again and again

Comment: "Just open the application link using selenium without coding for handling certificate, then accept it" - How would I do that?

Comment: I meant the simple to just to hit your application URL. Then manually accept the certificate.  from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('D:/Software/BrowsersDriver/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.securesite.com")

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, no luck. Even when attempting to pass no options, it simply says the site can't be reached.

Comment: No idea. In my case it worked. So in normal chrome browser when you hit that particular url manually second time then it doesn't ask to accept certificate in case you already accepted it once?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I accept the certificate the first time I load the site, if i refresh or visit another page then come back to the secured site, it doesnt prompt for the certificate, but rather just loads the site.

Comment: I too had this scenario. The process I followed manually, I did the same in Selenium, run the app, but didn't wrote code to close the browser, then I accepted certificate manually. Now when I run the script next I found it didn't ask for certificate